# How to run gulp in windows 7?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to run gulp on windows 7. I believe I have all dependencies but when I type `gulp` in the default `cmd` or posh-git, I receive the following error:

```
gulp : The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp
+ ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What should I do to make it work?

Here are the console messages I receive when trying to install gulp

```
npm install gulp - g
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/gulp
    npm http 200 https: //registry.npmjs.org/gulp
    npm WARN engine gulp@ 3.4.0: wanted: {
        "node": ">= 0.9"
    }(current: {
        "node": "v0.8.22",
        "npm": "1.2.14"
    })
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/orchestrator
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/pretty-hrtime
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/archy/0.0.2
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/semver
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl-fs/0.0.1
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/gulp-util
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/orchestrator
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/archy/0.0.2
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/pretty-hrtime
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/semver
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl-fs/0.0.1
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/gulp-util
    npm WARN engine vinyl - fs@ 0.0.1: wanted: {
        "node": ">= 0.9"
    }(current: {
        "node": "v0.8.22",
        "npm": "1.2.14"
    })
npm WARN engine gulp - util@ 2.2.20: wanted: {
    "node": ">= 0.9"
}(current: {
    "node": "v0.8.22",
    "npm": "1.2.14"
})
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/stream-consume
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/end-of-stream
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/sequencify
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/stream-consume
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/end-of-stream
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/sequencify
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob-watcher
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/map-stream
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob-stream
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/chalk
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/dateformat
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash._reinterpolate
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash.template
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/minimist
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/multipipe
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/through2
    npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob-watcher
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/map-stream
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/dateformat
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/chalk
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/glob-stream
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash._reinterpolate
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/lodash.template
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/minimist
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/multipipe
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/through2
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/vinyl
    npm WARN engine glob - watcher@ 0.0.8: wanted: {
        "node": ">= 0.9"
    }(current: {
        "node": "v0.8.22",
        "npm": "1.2.14"
    })
npm WARN engine glob - stream@ 3.1.18: wanted: {
    "node": ">= 0.9"
}(current: {
    "node": "v0.8.22",
    "npm": "1.2.14"
})
npm WARN engine vinyl@ 0.2.3: wanted: {
    "node": ">= 0.9"
}(current: {
    "node": "v0.8.22",
    "npm": "1.2.14"
})
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/once
    npm ERR!error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\optimist\test'
npm ERR!error rolling back gulp@ 3.4.0 {
    [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\optimist\test']
    npm ERR!error rolling back errno: 53,
        npm ERR!error rolling back code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
        npm ERR!error rolling back path: 'C:\\Users\\colecmc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\node_modules\\optimist\\test'
}
npm ERR!Error: No compatible version found: chalk@ '^0.5.0'
npm ERR!Valid install targets:
    npm ERR!["0.1.0", "0.1.1", "0.2.0", "0.2.1", "0.3.0", "0.4.0", "0.5.0", "0.5.1", "1.0.0"]
npm ERR!at installTargetsError(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ lib\ cache.js: 682: 10)
npm ERR!at C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ lib\ cache.js: 597: 10
npm ERR!at saved(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ npm - registry - client\ lib\ get.js: 138: 7)
npm ERR!at Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\findup-sync\node_modules\glob\glob.js'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ findup - sync\ node_modules\ glob\ glob.js
npm ERR!fstream_path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ findup - sync\ node_modules\ glob\ glob.js
npm ERR!fstream_type File
npm ERR!fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR!fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!fstream_stack Writer._finish(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ fstream\ lib\ writer.js: 305: 19)
npm ERR!fstream_stack Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\README.md'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ glob - stream\ README.md
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\vinyl\package.json'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ vinyl\ package.json
npm ERR!fstream_path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ vinyl\ package.json
npm ERR!fstream_type File
npm ERR!fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!fstream_stack C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ fstream\ lib\ writer.js: 284: 26
npm ERR!fstream_stack Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/once
    npm ERR!error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs'
npm ERR!error rolling back vinyl - fs@ 0.0.1 {
    [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful - fs ']
    npm ERR!error rolling back errno: 53,
        npm ERR!error rolling back code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
        npm ERR!error rolling back path: 'C:\\Users\\colecmc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\node_modules\\vinyl-fs\\node_modules\\graceful-fs'
}
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ graceful - fs\ polyfills.js
npm ERR!fstream_path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ graceful - fs\ polyfills.js
npm ERR!fstream_type File
npm ERR!fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!fstream_stack C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ fstream\ lib\ writer.js: 284: 26
npm ERR!fstream_stack Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\map-stream\.travis.yml'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ map - stream\.travis.yml
npm ERR!fstream_path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ vinyl - fs\ node_modules\ map - stream\.travis.yml
npm ERR!fstream_type File
npm ERR!fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!fstream_stack C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ fstream\ lib\ writer.js: 284: 26
npm ERR!fstream_stack Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm ERR!Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\colecmc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\findup-sync\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js'
npm ERR!If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR! < http: //github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR!or email it to:
    npm ERR! < npm - @googlegroups.com >

    npm ERR!System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install"
"gulp"
"-g"
npm ERR!cwd E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome
npm ERR!node - v v0.8.22
npm ERR!npm - v 1.2.14
npm ERR!path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ findup - sync\ node_modules\ lodash\ lodash.js
npm ERR!fstream_path C: \Users\ colecmc\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ gulp\ node_modules\ findup - sync\ node_modules\ lodash\ lodash.js
npm ERR!fstream_type File
npm ERR!fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR!code ENOENT
npm ERR!errno 34
npm ERR!fstream_stack C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ fstream\ lib\ writer.js: 284: 26
npm ERR!fstream_stack Object.oncomplete(fs.js: 297: 15)
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/wrappy
    npm http 304 https: //registry.npmjs.org/wrappy
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!Additional logging details can be found in :
    npm ERR!E: \DropBoxes\ DropBox\ experiments\ js\ extensions - chrome\ Eventum - master\ eventum - commit - log - chrome\ npm - debug.log
npm ERR!not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update #1

From the `npm` output it seems, that the version of node.js you have installed, is too old:

```
npm WARN engine gulp@ 3.4.0: wanted: {
    "node": ">= 0.9"
}(current: {
    "node": "v0.8.22",
    "npm": "1.2.14"
})
```

Your version is `0.8.22`, and gulp requires `0.9` or newer. Try upgrading your node.js first, and then try again.

#### Original answer

To install `gulp` you need to run this:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

This will install `gulp` globally, and that means the `gulp.cmd` will be accessible in

```
C:\Users\[yourAwesomeLogin]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

So, just make sure, you have that directory in your `PATH`.

Comment: I've done this several times to no avail. There are many red `npm ERR!` after the initial few green `npm http`

Comment: That would mean `gulp` is not installed. Perhaps you need to configure http proxy for `npm`? Please post the output ow `npm install gulp -g`, so we could see what happens there.

Comment: I will give it a shot and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I had to completely remove node and re-install from nodejs.org

Comment: this is the path by env variables : %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm